# ELOGIN error while connecting to SQL Server RDS in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: sql-server, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup SQL Server RDS using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am running a nodejs-express application to fetch details from the RDS. When I run app locally I am able to connect to RDS but when I deploy my application in Elastic Beanstalk I get `ELOGIN error - Login failed for user ***`. I have setup environment variables in the Software Configuration and stored them locally to connect to the RDS.

Answer (score 0):

You might receive an error if you attempt to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with a SQL Server account to log into SQL Server running on a Windows 2012 R2 EC2 instance or in Amazon RDS. The issue occurs when SSMS is run as a domain user and can result in the error "Login failed for user," even when valid credentials are provided. This is a known issue and AWS is actively working to resolve it.

To work around the issue, you can log into SQL Server with Windows Authentication instead of SQL Authentication. Or launch SSMS as a local user instead of a Simple AD domain user.

More Info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/admin_troubleshooting.html

Comment: I am not using SQL Server Management Studio. I am querying the database using `mssql` nodejs-module to fetch table details. I am able to connect to RDS server when I run it locally with no errors. The error is shown only when I deploy the application in the elastic beanstalk instance.

Comment: So try using Windows Authentication instead of SQL Authentication

Comment: I don't have any active directory structure setup. There is only a single username to login to the SQL Server.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with an ASP.net application. When running it locally with hard-coded connection string it connects fine but when using connection string from elastic beanstalk environment property I get login failed for user xxxx error. Did you ever resolve your issue?